# ViewState Issue - Custom Controls in a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I have a gridview that is populated on the Page_Load event if !PostBack is true.

The gridview has several column, each header template has a custom control that I'm using to sort the data in a more efficient way than what the ASP.NET gridview offers.

These custom controls have an OnSort event, I have tried defining them in the markup (was always null after postback) and hooking them up each time the page is loaded (now works).

Basically on a page postback, the ViewState for the custom controls in the gridview are being 'lost'. This is a problem as I have a Sort Direction field that toggles between Asc and Desc, and I rely heavily on the ViewState to remember the last value.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here? Or how I could change my code to keep the ViewState.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you're not paging, I would frankly forget all about using postbacks and viewstate to sort anything since it's so easy to use the [JQuery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo).   It takes all of the effort out of what you're doing, and at the same time provides a much smoother and faster interface for your users.

Comment: I'd love to use JQuery but I am bound to the technologies already in place (basically just ASP.NET/C#.Net etc). I am using paging, it is handled in a custom control and thus I have created sorting controls.